# Celery/systemd not talking to my django app

Tags: django, celery, wsgi, systemd

I am trying to daemonize my celery/redis workers on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am making progress! Celery is now running, but it does appear to be communicating with my django app. I found that removing the directive Type=forking from the celery.service file, celery started working.

```
# systemctl status celery.service
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-12-17 18:35:19 MST; 1min 52s ago
 Main PID: 21509 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/celery.service

Dec 17 18:35:17 t-rex systemd[1]: Starting Celery Service...
Dec 17 18:35:19 t-rex sh[24331]: celery multi v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
Dec 17 18:35:19 t-rex sh[24331]: > Starting nodes...
Dec 17 18:35:19 t-rex sh[24331]:         > w1@t-rex: OK
Dec 17 18:35:19 t-rex sh[24331]:         > w2@t-rex: OK
Dec 17 18:35:19 t-rex sh[24331]:         > w3@t-rex: OK
Dec 17 18:35:19 t-rex systemd[1]: Started Celery Service.
```

When I test celery from the python prompt in my apps virtualenv the test fails. This is the test I use in my app before I call a celery task.

```
>>> celery_app.control.broadcast('ping', reply=True, limit=1)
[]
```

My celery.service file (straight from [the celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd)) with a few local changes.

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target redis.service
Requires=redis.service

[Service]
#Type=forking
User=www-data
Group=www-data
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/home/mark/python-projects/archive
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi start $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}"'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A $CELERY_APP multi restart $CELERYD_NODES \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel="${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}" $CELERYD_OPTS'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my environment file (also from the same celery docs):

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/home/mark/.virtualenvs/archive/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="MemorabiliaJSON"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"
```

The redis server is running, so that not be the issue. I am not sure if redis is talking to my daemonized celery or not.

I start celery with "celery -A MemorabiliaJSON worker -l debug" when using django runserver, and I am not sure if my daemonized celery needs something else to make it talk to my django apps.

Is there any magic needed to get django/apache/wsgi to work with daemonized celery? There is nothing in the celery log files when I try my test above.

Thanks for any assistance you can give me in debugging this problem!

Mark

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?